# Testing Logger with Adapter Pattern

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, nunit, adapter

I have a class and want to test if the method is called, the logger logs.

```
public class LoggerAdapter<TheClassWhichHasTheMethod>: ILoggerAdapter<etc>
```

This is the Adapter i made. So i have the methods i am using and need in the logger class and have put them inside the adapter logger class

```
public void MethodOne(param1, param2, param3, param4)
```

And this void method on its own calls the next method inside the adapter:

```
public void MethodTwo(param1, param2, param3, param4)
```

After that the logging is finished. But wait, there is more. The method where the logger is doing its job goes like this:

```
 public async Task Execute()
    {
        await //some logic

        //some more logic
       Here the logger does its job: _logger.MethodOne(param1, param2, param3)
     //After logging finishes, more logic follows
    }
```

Now, the Interface of the Adapter needs to Extend `ILogger` because I need the ILogger as one of my `param`. The thing is, after I do the `Act` part:

```
//await _classInstance.Execute();
```

And since I am testing a void method there is some timeout. Okay, the timeout finishes but after that I have no idea how to Verify if the logger has logged i.e _classInstance.Execute() starts, logger calls MethodOne, which calls MethodTwo and after that it finishes.

Answer (score 0):

You know I'd suggest you to use library `Moq`. This library has cool method `Verify` where you can test was your method called or not. 
You need to do something like this:

`var objectA = new Mock<ObjectA>();`//ObjectA has Method1, Method2. Method1, Method2 must be public virtual or belong to an interface thus ObjectA has to implement this interface;

Then `objectA.Verify(o=>o.Method1(), Times.Once);`//And the same with Method2.

Comment: @EdwardchoVaklinov what error do you have? In Test explorer in Visual Studio you can check why your test fails. Remember your methods MUST be or in interface nor public virtual. THATS ESSENTIAL

Comment: @Nolmagination The invocation did not happen at all. But when I debug it  goes through both MethodOne & MethodTwo. Maybe I am passing the wrong object as param?

Comment: @EdwardchoVaklinov Yes, most possibly it is so. You should write something like this in parameters `objectA.Verify(o=>o.Method1(It.IsAny<param1_type>(), It.IsAny<param2_type>()........))`